Selenium not detecting an element and I can't switch to shadow-root internal structure
I am trying to scrap links from a website but I can't seem to be able to locate the element related to the products.
The website = https://www.cvlinens.com/collections/table-linens?page=3
My code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.cvlinens.com/collections/table-linens?page=3'
driver.get(url)

  

try:
    load = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'products-grid')))
except:
    driver.close()
    print('failed')

It keeps returning 'failed'. I have tried finding the element by xpath and css selector aswell, but no luck.
I read somewhere about iframes and how I would need to switch to the iframe containing the element to access it. But I can't switch to the iframe. It returns 'failed' aswell.

The element you are looking for is inside a shadow-root.
<div id="fast-simon-serp-app" style="display: block; color: initial; background: initial; min-height: unset;">
  #shadow-root (open)

You were heading down a similar path thinking about IFRAMEs. These are similar but the syntax and how you handle them is different.

NOTE: As of Chrome v96, the JS syntax quoted in another answer is no longer used.

The updated syntax is below and I've tested that it works.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url = 'https://www.cvlinens.com/collections/table-linens?page=3'
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
shadow_host = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fast-simon-serp-app')))
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
load = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, 'products-grid')
print(load.text)


Your element is placed inside shadow-root, to get internal shadow root structure, you should get it's host first and then get shadowRoot property.
Shadow host in current example is element with id fast-simon-serp-app
get_shadow_root function gets shadow root from host, using JS executor.
More about Shadow DOM
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
timeout = 10
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

driver.get("https://www.cvlinens.com/collections/table-linens?page=3")
driver.maximize_window()

shadow_host = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "fast-simon-serp-app")))
shadow_container = get_shadow_root(shadow_host)
grid = shadow_container.find_element(By.ID, 'products-grid')

